# Splitting polygons leaves null values

Tags: polygon, arcgis-10.1, topology, splitting

I'm trying to split polygons with overlaping line features, using Split Polygons tool from Topology toolbar. The problem I encounter is that only one from new polygons have old attributes and others only null values. I'm using arcgis 10.1.

Answer (score 2):

That can be managed with the split/merge policy.
I believe that domains would be required to enable this functionality.
take a look at the split policy in the [domain section of help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001s00000001000000)

> **Split policies**
>
> An attribute for any given table, feature class, or subtype can have
>   one of three split policies that control the value of an attribute in
>   the output object:
>
> - Default value—The attributes of the two resulting features take on the default value for the attribute of the given feature class or subtype.
> - Duplicate—The attribute of the two resulting features takes on a copy of the original object's attribute value.
> - Geometry ratio—The attributes of resulting features are a ratio of the
>     original feature's value. The ratio is based on the ratio in which the
>     original geometry is divided. If the geometry is divided equally, each
>     new feature's attribute gets one-half of the value of the original
>     object's attribute. Geometry ratio policies only apply to domains for
>     numeric field types.
>
> [image: from esir]
>   In the parcel example above, when a parcel is split, the Area
>   attribute is automatically assigned as a property of the resulting
>   geometry. The value for Owner is copied to the new objects (in this
>   database, splitting a parcel does not affect its ownership). The
>   PropertyTax is calculated based on the area, or size, of a parcel. To
>   calculate the PropertyTax for each of the new objects, the split
>   policy divides the PropertyTax of the original parcel proportionally
>   among the new features according to their area.

If you do much topology you should already be aware of the topology rules.
they can be found here [topology poster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/01mm/pdf/topology_rules_poster.pdf)
topology help is [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01mm0000000m000000)